# Booksleeve Redis development guide

Tags: redis, booksleeve

Is there an article or resource on getting started with BookSleeve Redis? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Book sleeve is just a wrapper around redis, so any data decisions really relate equally to any redis guide. http://redis.io would be a starting place. In terms of the API, the only things that should need highlighting are:

- most operations are async and are exposed via the Task api; this allows a range of usage patterns including (but not limited to) the new "async"/"await" keywords
- the operations are split by data type, so .Strings, .Hashes, etc
- a connection is a thread-safe multiplexer and is designed to be used by multiple callers concurrently - you do not (and should not) need to use a connection scoped per caller

I am interested in what things you would want me to include in more detailed documentation. What would be useful? What is unclear? What do you need?

If you can describe what you need, I can write it :p

Answer (score 5):

These are some of the articles/links I read when getting upto speed:

http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/04/async-redis-await-booksleeve.html

http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/07/booksleeve-transactions-hashes-and.html

https://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/

http://redis.io/

besides that, search stackoverflow for related questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booksleeve

There is not a ton out there, you need to roll up your sleeves and dig in.